# sqlCacheDependency for Azure Blobs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, outputcache, azure-blob-storage

Does `SqlCacheDependency` works for Azure Blob Storage?

I have action which gets some blob from storage (values is most of time as constants). I try to use OutputCache for this action. Then I try to use `SqlCacheDependency` to clear cache if in blob is some changes, but this doesn't work.

So how can I use `SqlCacheDependency` or something similar to it for Blobs?

```
[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(Duration = int.MaxValue, VaryByParam = "none")]
public ActionResult GetCalculatorSalaries()
{
    var salaries = _service.LoadCalculatorSalaries();
    return Json(salaries, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Azure Blob Storage is not SQL, so I'd say no.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no relationship between an Azure Blob and SQL Azure - so sqlCacheDependency will not work.

The new (preview) [Azure Redis Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn690523.aspx) is probably worth investigating.